# How do I load a lot of data at once in a Cassandra "cluster" of one node?

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am working on a multi website system which uses Cassandra to handle all of its data needs.

When I first install a website, it adds 3918 pages (and growing) with many fields, attachments such as JS files, links between pages, etc.

At some point, my test "cluster" (one node) decides that the data is coming to fast and it times out or worst, Cassandra "crashes" because of an out of memory (OOM). More or less, from what I can see the 2Gb of RAM allocated by Cassandra fills up and then, more often than not, Cassandra does not control its available RAM and gets an OOM. When I don't get the OOM, I get timeouts.

Is there a call in the C/C++ driver to know whether the "cluster" is slow so I can wait for a while instead of pushing more data like crazy?

At this point, the only thing I can see is me doing a write (`INSERT INTO ...`) and getting a Timeout error. More precisely, this error: `CASS_ERROR_SERVER_WRITE_TIMEOUT`. I find it rather ugly to wait until I get such an error to start pacing my `INSERT`s in order to manage the load. Is that the only way?!

---

Update: I was able to avoid the OOM, but only by reducing the number of plugins that get installed on first website creation (I do not need to have all the plugins installed at once). This is not a good solution, if you ask me, because a Cassandra node should NOT just crash like that. This could (probably does happen to many) happen in production and that's intolerable to think that could happen any time the load goes a tad bit too high for a minute...

Answer (score 2):

What I personally do to load lots of data is using asynchronuous queries (that's in Python but I think you can do the same thing in C++). I insert my data in asynchronuous fashion, and put the responses into a list.

When I reached a certain number (1000 in my case), I browse my list and call the results of all my responses to block synchronously until all my queries passed.

This way, I can send lots of queries without overloading my cluster. Don't know if it's the most efficient way, but that's work good.

Comment: Are you saying that asynchronous queries are not marked "done" until the node(s) are not 100% done with them? That would be an interesting side effect... I would have thought that synchronous queries would work exactly like that?

Comment: No, it's the effect of asynchronous. If you had to wait the acknowledgement of the node, it would be synchronous. The interest of asynchronous is that you don't have to wait, and so you can save some time. But it can overload the node, and use a list prevent this : when you ask future, the majority of queries are already done, and you just have to wait to the last queries to finish.

Comment: For a use case that's OOMing under write load, firing off 1k async queries is likely to make things worse, not better.

Answer (score 2):

Single node clusters are atypical (they're not antipatterns, but they're not the primary use case). You'll have to work around some traditional behaviors.

1) Use sync queries instead of asynchronous.

2) Make sure you use a real consistency level ( `QUORUM` ) even on a single node, as using `ANY` will let you be overwhelmed.

3) Measure your own query latency. If latencies increase pass a certain point (short of a full timeout), back off insertion rate (artificially sleep).

4) Tune the cassandra side of the connection. 2GB is pretty small, to run that effectively you'll need to do some tuning. You'll probably want to tune your memtable flush thresholds to encourage more frequent flushing, and maybe explicitly configure memtable sizes based on the size of your initial document set.

Comment: Well... I succeeded, but only because I found out that I was trying to install more plugins all at once than I needed to. Removing those extras fixed the crashing issue, although obviously the potential for Cassandra to crash is still very much there... So in effect I send much less data to Cassandra as a result and do not get the OOM.

Answer (score 0):

See **[Cassandra Loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader)** to ingest massive data into Cassandra.

Comment: That won't work for us because we do not have a CVS to just upload. The keys vary depending on each installation, time changes too...