# Can I force a Cassandra table flush from the C/C++ driver like nodetool does?

Tags: c++, cassandra, driver, cassandra-3.0

I'm wondering whether I could replicate the `forceKeyspaceFlush()` function found in the nodetool utility from the C/C++ driver of Cassandra.

The nodetool function looks like this:

```
public class Flush extends NodeToolCmd
{
    @Arguments(usage = "[<keyspace> <tables>...]", description = "The keyspace followed by one or many tables")
    private List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void execute(NodeProbe probe)
    {
        List<String> keyspaces = parseOptionalKeyspace(args, probe);
        String[] tableNames = parseOptionalTables(args);

        for (String keyspace : keyspaces)
        {
            try
            {
                probe.forceKeyspaceFlush(keyspace, tableNames);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred during flushing", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to replicate in my C++ software is this line:

```
probe.forceKeyspaceFlush(keyspace, tableNames);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

That's an unusual request, primarily because Cassandra is designed to be distributed, so if you're executing a query, you'd need to perform that blocking flush on each of the (potentially many) replicas. Rather than convince you that you don't really need this, I'll attempt to answer your question - however, you probably don't really need this.

Nodetool is using the JMX interface (on tcp/7199) to force that flush - Your c/c++ driver talks over the native protocol (on tcp/9042). At this time, flush is not possible via [the native protocol](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec).

Work around the limitation, you'd need to either exec a jmx-capable commandline utility (nodetool or other), implement a JMX client in c++ (it's been done), or extend the native protocol. None of those are particularly pleasant options, but I imagine executing a jmx CLI utility is significantly easier than the other two.

Comment: Well... This is in link with that other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689227/how-do-i-load-a-lot-of-data-at-once-in-a-cassandra-cluster-of-one-node#answer-36713619 -- it looks like without a clear flush, I will not be able to NOT crash Cassandra. I know that if I had a 20 node cluster, I'd be fine because that's not that much data. In a one node test, however, the node gets swamped pretty quickly, unfortunately.